# Naming this iron complex: Fe2Cl6[H2O]5

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, nomenclature, coordination-compounds

This is the iron complex in question:

$\ce{Fe2Cl6[H2O]5}$

I'm pretty sure according to the nomenclature it should be: pentaaquahexachloroiron(III) but I wanted to check somewhere to be sure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In coordination chemistry square brackets denote inner coordination sphere; $\ce{[H2O]5}$ makes little sense in this context.
It looks like the correct molecular formula for this compound appears to be $\ce{[FeCl2(H2O)4]+[FeCl4]- * H2O}$ according to the crystal structure determined by Szymański [[1](https://doi.org/10.1107/S0567740879008244)].

The IUPAC-compliant name proposed by the author is **tetraaqua-*cis*-dichloroiron(III) tetrachloroferrate(III) monohydrate**.

[image: Crystal structure of FeCl2(H2O)4]⁺[FeCl4]⁻·H2O]

**Figure 1.** Asymmetric unit $\ce{[FeCl2(H2O)4]+[FeCl4]- * H2O}$ (ICSD-8198) with added hydrogen atoms.
Color code: $\color{#EEEEEE}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{H}$; $\color{#FF0D0D}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{O}$; $\color{#1FF01F}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{Cl}$; $\color{#E06633}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{Fe}$.

### References

1. Szymański, J. T. The Crystal Structure of Tetraaqua-*cis*-Dichloroiron(III) Tetrachloroferrate(III) Monohydrate (Ferric Chloride $2\frac 1 2$-Hydrate). *Acta Cryst. B* **1979**, *B35* (9), 1958–1963. https://doi.org/10.1107/S0567740879008244.